# window.performance (Navigation Timing) - how to get this reported in "analytics way"

Tags: analytics, performance

I have recently learned about [window.performance](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html) that seems a great way to measure webapp performance using real client traffic. Is there any analytics service that is built on top of this and allows to capture performance metrics from across the world with little effort?

I am looking for something like google analytics that requires you to add few lines of JavaScript and everything is taken care of ... preferably something that can be hosted in intranet.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to do a little work to find this out, as it's low-level enough that it's the sort of thing most users just don't have to care about. You're not going to see it on the front-page feature list, for example. I'd guess there's a good chance *many* services tracking this kind of information are likely using the spec and just don't have much reason to talk about it, unless you dig up a very technical blog post from them.

That said, Google Analytics [*does* make use of this](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1205784) for their site speed reporting. (ref. the grey box about halfway down the page)

[Yottaa](http://www.yottaa.com/) is a service specifically concerned with performance metrics(rather than it being in addition to traffic like GA), and also makes use of it, as mentioned in [this blog post](http://blog.yottaa.com/2011/03/w3c-navigation-timing-api-better-page-load-time-measurements-in-chrome-and-ie).

I haven't found it in reference to self-installed analytics applications. It's been [proposed for Piwik](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/ticket/1700?version=2), at least, so that may be worth checking in the future.